# How to show that inequation

Tags: integration

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Let $f''(x)$ : conti-function and $|f''(x)|<M(M>0)$ on $[a,b]$

then  show that

for all $x\in [a,b]$ and $c\in [a,b]$ such that $$|f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)(x-c)|\leq \frac{M(x-c)^2}{2}$$

Comment: I'm fairly certain this should be a consequence of the mean value theorem. Have you tried applying that?

Comment: yes i tried but

Comment: See my answer below. It's not quite MVT, but a generalization known as Taylor's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer given by @Xiaolang for the most part. Explicitly, however, Taylor's Theorem with the explicit formula for the remainder (see [Taylor's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem)) says there is a $\xi$ between $x$ and $c$ so that 
$$
f(x) = f(c) + f^{\prime}(c)(x-c) + f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)\frac{(x-c)^2}{2}.
$$
Subtracting $f(c) + f^{\prime}(c)(x-c)$ from both sides, taking the absolute value, and applying the given estimate for $f^{\prime\prime}$ gives
$$
|f(x) - f(c) - f^{\prime}(c)(x-c)| = \left| f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)\frac{(x-c)^2}{2} \right| \leq M \frac{(x-c)^2}{2}
$$
as desired.

Comment: "the above post" may not stay above if your answer gets more upvotes.. Please consider changing the wording.

Comment: Sure thing! I added the "above" poster's name.

Answer (score 1):

it's obvious we should use the Taylor series
in fact

$$
f(x)=f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+f''(c)(x-c)^2/2+o(x^2) 
$$
$$
f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)(x-c)=f''(c)(x-c)^2/2+o(x^2) 
$$

$$
丨f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)(x-c)丨<= M(x-c)^2/2
$$